# Removing Element In XML using PHP function

Tags: php, xml, function

i have an array like this

```
Array
(
    [351] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [unit_id] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 10192
                            [1] => 10192
                            [2] => 10192
                        )
                    [born_from] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1980-08-21
                        )
                    [born_to] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2010-08-18
                        )
                    [start_date] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2013-02-21 17:29:00
                        )
                    [sex] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 3
                        )
                    [id] => 351
                    [product_id] => 1
                    [name] => test1
                )

        )
)
```

i have written a PHP function to convert this array in to xml

function is

```
function generate_xml_from_array($array, $node_name) {
    $xml = '';

    if (is_array($array) || is_object($array)) {
        foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
            if (is_numeric($key)) {
                $key = $node_name;
            }

            $xml .= '<' . $key . '>' . "\n" . generate_xml_from_array($value, $node_name) . '</' . $key . '>' . "\n";
        }
    } else {
        $xml = htmlspecialchars($array, ENT_QUOTES) . "\n";
    }

    return $xml;
}

function generate_valid_xml_from_array($array, $node_block='products', $node_name='node') {
    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>' . "\n";
    $xml .= '<' . $node_block . '>' . "\n";
    $xml .= generate_xml_from_array($array, $node_name);
    $xml .= '</' . $node_block . '>' . "\n";

    return $xml;
}

$xml = generate_valid_xml_from_array($MyArray);
file_put_contents('C:/product.xml',$xml);
```

this gives me output like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<products>
<node>
    <node>
    <unit_id><node>10192</node><node>10192</node><node>10192</node></unit_id>
    <born_from><node>1980-08-21</node></born_from>
    <born_to><node>2010-08-18</node></born_to>
    <start_date><node>2013-02-21 17:29:00</node></start_date>
    <sex><node>3</node></sex>
    <id>351</id>
    <product_id>1</product_id>
    <name>test1</name>
    </node>
</node>
</products>
```

in this output there is a `<node>` which is increasing the file size any way to remove this `<node>` so the file size will not increase

Comment: Can you describe your problem a little better? Are you concerned that everything is wrapped in a `<node>` or, is there one single node you're trying to get rid of?

Comment: @Nicholas Pickering here everything is wrapped in `<node>` i dont want that `<node>` just because of it the file size is increasing..

Comment: @Nicholas i want something like `<product> <node> <unit_id> ... </unit_id>  ... <name>test1</name></node> <node> data of 352 </node></product>`

Answer (score 0):

Change your Function Like This

```
function generate_xml_from_array($array, $node_name) {
$xml = '';

if (is_array($array) || is_object($array)) {

    foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
        if (is_numeric($key) ) {

        if(count($array)>1)
             {
        $xml .= '<' . $node_name . '>' . "\n" . generate_xml_from_array($value, $node_name) . '</' . $node_name . '>' . "\n";
             }
          else
            {
        $xml .= generate_xml_from_array($value, $node_name). "\n";  
            }

        }
      else{ 
            $xml .= '<' . $key . '>' . "\n" . generate_xml_from_array($value, $node_name) . '</' . $key . '>' . "\n";}
          }
} else {
    $xml = htmlspecialchars($array, ENT_QUOTES) . "\n";
}

return $xml;
     }
```

and You'll get following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<products>
<unit_id>
<node>10192</node> 
<node>10192</node> 
<node>10192</node> 
</unit_id>
<born_from>1980-08-21</born_from> 
<born_to>2010-08-18</born_to> 
<start_date>2013-02-21 17:29:00</start_date> 
<sex>3</sex> 
<id>351</id> 
<product_id>1</product_id> 
<name>test1</name> 
</products>
```